# Rewrite url from HTTPS to HTTP

Tags: regex, apache, ssl, url-rewriting

Have issue in rewrite url.

//This should redirect from https:// to http:// if the path does not begin with 'purchase'
or it doesn't end in css, jpg, jpeg, gif, png, js, ico or axd - the file types used in 'purchase'and allow ssl to the 'purWs'.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^(?!purWS)(?!purchase)(?!SRC.axd\?.*)(?!WRC.axd\?.*)(.*)(?<!\.css)(?<!\.js)(?<!\.jpg)(?<!\.jpeg)(?<!\.gif)(?<!\.png)(?<!\.ico)$
http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1
```

I am no experienced in regex rules syntax.
Could you please let me know where is an issue?

Comment: `RedirectRule`? you mean `RewriteRule`?

Comment: yes. the issue is in regex syntax

Comment: `(?:^https://(?!purchase)|\.(?:css|jpg|gif|png|js|ico|axd)$)` does as you required except for the "purWS", because I don't understand what you are trying to say. That said, users would likely prefer that you just provide everything over SSL, and the overhead is negligible on modern hardware.